# Angular Material: ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, angular-material, publish-subscribe, mat-select, mat-form-field

Good afternoon!

These days i've been working on to a pokemon-based project which consists in getting a random attack (1 of 4 strings) just by choosing in two selects (the trainer and the pokemon one).

Unfortunately, it appears the mentioned on the title despite even though i have the following issues:

- MatFormField and MatSelect modules imported.
- any NgIfs inside the mat-form-field.
- matNativeControl attribute inside the mat-select tag.
- error case inside the .subcribe() method

Basically, i don't understand why it's happening on what else i should look for.

First i'll show you the HTML:

```
    <mat-card class="attack-form">
      <mat-card-header id="attacks">
        <mat-card-title class="h4">Random Attack Generator</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <form id="form-attacks" [formGroup]="attacksForm" (ngSubmit)="generateRandomAttack()">
          <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
            <mat-label>Selecciona un entrenador</mat-label>
            <mat-select matNativeControl formControlName="trainerName">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let trainer of trainers" [value]="trainer.fullName">
                {{trainer.fullName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
            <mat-label>Selecciona un pokemon</mat-label>
            <mat-select matNativeControl formControlName="pokemonName">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons" [value]="pokemon.fullName">
                {{pokemon.fullName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="lifeUnderFifty">Click if life is under 50%</mat-checkbox>
          </mat-form-field>
          <button type="submit" mat-raised-button [disabled]="!attacksForm.valid" >Generate random attack!</button>
        </form>
      </mat-card-conten   t>
    </mat-card>
```

Next, the controller:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Trainer } from 'src/app/models/trainer';
    import { ObtainDataService } from 'src/app/services/obtain-data.service';
    import { Pokemon } from 'src/app/models/pokemon';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { AttacksService } from 'src/app/services/attack-functions.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'attack-form',
      templateUrl: './attack-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./attack-form.component.scss']
    })
    export class AttackFormComponent implements OnInit {

      public attacksForm!: FormGroup;

      trainers: Trainer[] = [];
      trainerName: string = '';
      pokemons: Pokemon[] = [];
      pokemonName: string = '';
      rage: boolean = false;

      constructor( private obtainData: ObtainDataService, private attackService: AttacksService){

      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.obtainData.getTrainers().subscribe( {
          next: (entrenadores: Trainer[]) => this.trainers = entrenadores,
          error: (err: Error) => console.log('Hubo un error en el observable '),
          complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'), 
        });

        this.obtainData.getTrainers2().subscribe( {
          next: (entrenadores: Trainer[]) => { this.trainers = entrenadores } ,
          error: (err: Error) => { console.log('Hubo un error en el observable :' + err)} ,
          complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'), 
        });

        this.attacksForm = new FormGroup({
          trainerName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
          pokemonName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
          lifeUnderFifty: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        })

      }

      generateRandomAttack(){
        this.trainerName = this.attacksForm.controls['trainerName'].value;
        this.pokemonName = this.attacksForm.controls['pokemonName'].value;
        this.attackService.selectAttack(this.trainers, this.trainerName, this.pokemonName, this.rage );
      }

    }
```

And finally, the angular material module:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
    import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
    import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
    import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
    import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule
      ],
      exports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule
      ]
    })
    export class AngularMaterialModule { }
```

What do you think is causing the error? How do you solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK you do not need to wrap `mat-checkbox` with `mat-form-field`

Comment: @nevzatopcu, amazing, that was the mistake. Thanks a lot!